# How does one cluster by dissimilarity rather than similarity? Is using inverse Euclidean distance acceptable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to cluster a suite of products by how **dissimilar** they are rather than by how similar they are.
That is, if Product1 is selling in Week 1 and not selling in Week 2, I want to pair it with a Product that is not selling in Week 1 but is selling in Week 2.

As the end product, I'd like to present a seaborn clustermap that illustrate the inverse relationship between products.

I have attempted to use the Inverse of Euclidean distance as my clustering metric as opposed to Euclidean distance. to achieve this task.

Sample code below:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(2,size=(5,10))
```

Sample dataframe, Five products with 10 "weeks" of data. 1 = Sales, 0 = No Sales

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a, 
                  index='Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4 Product5'.split(),
                  columns=np.arange(1,11))
```

Define distance metric, inverse of Euclidean distance:

```
invEucl = lambda u, v: 1 / np.sqrt(((u-v)**2).sum())
```

Compare clustermaps, Euclidean vs Inverse:

```
sns.clustermap(df,col_cluster=False)

sns.clustermap(df,
               col_cluster=False,
              metric=invEucl)
```

The results seem to work graphically, with the clustermap grouping dissimilar items together, but I want to confirm that using something like an Inverse of Euclidean distance is appropriate.

If it is, are you aware of any literature that uses a similar approach?

If not, are there any metrics out there that would be appropriate for this type of analysis? 
Essentially I am looking for a metric that will assign a lower distance to vectors that are least similar.

Comment: Clustering by dissimilarity doesn't make any sense. If `a` and `b` are highly similar, and `b` and `c` are highly similar, then `a` and `c` are at least pretty similar, but if `a` and `b` are highly dissimilar, and `b` and `c` are highly dissimilar, that tells us nothing about how similar or dissimilar `a` and `c` are. They could be identical.

Comment: Normally I would recommend clustering similar items and then detecting the outliers from the clusters detected, to find those points that "don't belong" and are distant from all the clusters.

Comment: Alternately, perhaps you are really just looking for the N maximum values in the distance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering by dissimilarity doesn't make any sense. If `a` and `b` are highly similar, and `b` and `c` are highly similar, then `a` and `c` are at least pretty similar, but if `a` and `b` are highly dissimilar, and `b` and `c` are highly dissimilar, that tells us nothing about how similar or dissimilar `a` and `c` are. They could be identical.

Your clustering "metric" is fundamentally broken. It doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality; there is no guarantee that `dist(a, c) <= dist(a, b) + dist(b, c)`.

Clustering is the wrong approach here.